# How to load parrot SDL pir module in rakudo?

Tags: sdl, raku, rakudo

I don't know how to load de parrot SDL module in rakudo. I've found a [example](http://github.com/quietfanatic/gamebase/blob/master/SDL.pm) to do that with pir code.

But... there is any way to load pir SDL module into rakudo with perl code?

Answer (score 1):

How about just `use SDL;`? That's how it should work, and that's what I see in the examples.